# Python argparser mutually exclusive with same argument in multiple groups

Tags: python, argparse

I use argparser as a generic way to provide inputs on multiple different files, that are used to generate at the end a json, and sent to a database.
Have that said, I want to use multiple mutually exclusive groups, with the option to a flag being part of multiple different groups (as in the example below).

```
parser = argparser.argumentParser

group1 = parser.add_mutually_exclusive_group()
group2 = parser.add_mutually_exclusive_group(required=True)
group3 = parser.add_mutually_exclusive_group()

group1.add_argument('-a', type=int) 
group1.add_argument('-d', type=int)

group2.add_argument('-z', type=int)
group2.add_argument('-x', type=int)

group3.add_argument('-a', type=int)
group3.add_argument('-z', type=int)
```

it means that -d and -z can go together (but -z or -x are mandatory), giving me the option to have -a -d -x OR -z -d

for some reason, the argparser thinks each one of the -a or -z flags are conflicting, so i have added the conflict_handler to 'resolve', but seems to have no effect

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you add an argument to a `group`, it is also added to the `parser`.  Groups, both `argument_group` and `mutually_exclusive_group` are ways of defining some special actions (in help and testing), but they don't change the fundamental parsing.

So the arguments you try to define via `group3` conflict with the arguments already defined via the other groups.  I should also note that `add_argument` creates an argument `Action` object.

For a bug/issue I came up with a way of adding pre existing Actions to a new group.  That is, a way of adding the `-a` and `-z` that were created earlier to `group3`.  Actually I wrote it as a way defining a group with a list of existing Actions.  That wasn't very hard to do.  But displaying such a group required a major rewrite to the `usage` formatter.

https://bugs.python.org/issue10984

`mutually_exclusive_group` does 2 things - it modifies the `usage` - if possible.  And it does the 'mutually-exclusive' test.  Otherwise it does not modify the parsing.  You could perform the same tests after parsing.

In your example, all arguments have a default of `None`.  So after parsing, you could do:

```
if args.a is not None and args.z is not None:
   parse.error('cannot use both -a and -z')
```

---

In the bug/issue I modified `add_mutually_exclusive_group` to effectively do:

```
group1 = parser.add_mutually_exclusive_group()
group2 = parser.add_mutually_exclusive_group(required=True)

a1 = group1.add_argument('-a', type=int) # hang onto the newly created Action
group1.add_argument('-d', type=int)

a2 = group2.add_argument('-z', type=int)
group2.add_argument('-x', type=int)

group3 = parser.add_mutually_exclusive_group()
group3._group_actions.append(a1)      # add existing Action to group
group3._group_actions.append(a2)
#group3.add_argument('-a', type=int)
#group3.add_argument('-z', type=int)
```

That is, pointers to the existing `Actions` are added directly to the new group, without going through `add_argument`.

testing `group3`:

```
2347:~/mypy$ python3 stack47670008.py -z 3 -a3
usage: stack47670008.py [-h] [-a A | -d D] (-z Z | -x X)
stack47670008.py: error: argument -a: not allowed with argument -z

2347:~/mypy$ python3 stack47670008.py -z 3 -d3
Namespace(a=None, d=3, x=None, z=3)

2347:~/mypy$ python3 stack47670008.py -h
usage: stack47670008.py [-h] [-a A | -d D] (-z Z | -x X)

optional arguments:
  -h, --help  show this help message and exit
  -a A
  -d D
  -z Z
  -x X
```

`group1` and `group2` show up in the usage, but not `group3`.

Comment: it can indeed work, but i'm extending the arparser class to, at the end, parse all the arguments to a json, in a generic way, to save them for internal purposes in a DB. Your suggestion will sure work for a single python file, but i have hundreds, and adding advanced logic to all of them apparently will be too much...

Comment: I've expanded a bit on what my bug/issue suggestion does.  If you are already extending argparse, you could easily modify the `add_mutually_exclusive_group` method.

Comment: so it means i can "re-send" the actions, instead of creating the new arguments many times?
i will test it and post my results.
Thank you.

Comment: worked perfectly, and now I can create as many groups as I need, with as many (repeated or not) attributes as I need. Thank you.

Answer (score -1):

I think what you're looking for is the `sub_parsers` option from argparse.
Kindly check the link from the python docs [add_subparsers](https://docs.python.org/dev/library/argparse.html#sub-commands).

Comment: nope, i need it to be in a single command, but i use multiple flags (a more practical example - run an external tool that uses multiple flags, but few of them are mutually exclusive).